# Parse string into and unknown amount of regex groups in C++

Tags: c++, regex, parsing

I know the exact format of the text I should be getting.  In particular, it should match a regex with a variable number of groups.

I want to use the C++ regex library to determine (a) if it is valid text, and (b) to parse those groups into a vector.  How can I do this?  I can find examples online to do (a), but not (b).

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>

bool parse_this_text(std::string & text, std::vector<std::string> & group) {
    // std::string text_regex = "^([a-z]*)(,[0-9]+)*$"

    // if the text matches the regex, return true and parse each group into the vector
    // else return false
    ???
}
```

Such that the following lines of code return the expected results.

```
std::vector<std::string> group;

parse_this_text("green,1", group);
// should return true with group = {"green", ",1"};

parse_this_text("yellow", group);
// should return true with group = {"yellow"};

parse_this_text("red,1,2,3", group);
// should return true with group = {"red", ",1", ",2", ",3"};

parse_this_text("blue,1.0,3.0,1,a", group);
// should return false (since it doesn't match the regex)
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator

Answer (score 0):

```
   (?=^([a-zA-Z]*)(?:\,\d+)+$)^.*?(?:((?:\,\d+)+)).*?$
```

You can use this.This will first validate using lookahead and then return 2 groups.

1) containing name

2) containing all the rest of integers (This can be easily split) or you can use re.findall here

Though it doesnot answer your question fully , it might be of help.

Have a look.

http://regex101.com/r/wE3dU7/3

Comment: `re.findall` is a python function, not a C++ method. And you can achieve the same effect (which is not what's being requested) with a much simpler regex, rather similar to the one in the OP: `^([[:alpha:]]*)((,[[:digit:]]+)*)$`

Answer (score 0):

One option is to scan the string twice, the first time to check for validity and the second time to split it into fields. With the example in the OP, you don't really need regexen to split the line, once you know that it is correct; you can simply split on commas. But for the sake of exposition, you could use a `std::regex_token_iterator` (assuming you have a C++ library which supports those), something like this:

```
bool parse_this_text(const std::string& s, std::vector<std::string>& result) {
  static const std::regex check("[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*(,[[:digit:]])*",
                                std::regex_constants::nosubs);
  static const std::regex split(",");
  if (!std::regex_match(s, check)) 
    return false;
  std::sregex_token_iterator tokens(s.begin(), s.end(), split, -1); 
  result.clear();
  std::copy(tokens, std::sregex_token_iterator(), std::back_inserter(result));
  return true;
}
```

For more complicated cases, or applications in which the double scan is undesired, you can tokenize using successive calls to `std::regex_search()`, supplying the end of the previous match as the starting point, and `std::regex_constants::continuous` as the match flags; that will anchor each search to the character after the previous match. You could, in that case, use a `std::regex_iterator`, but I'm not convinced that the resulting code is any simpler.